# support appcompat is not compile Android Studio

Tags: android

I just updated my Android Studio to 2.3.1 and I'm getting this error in my gradle

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'
```

All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found versions 25.3.1, 25.1.1. Examples include com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:25.3.1 and com.android.support:support-v13:25.1.1

So I did update the line to :

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
```

And still not working! The SDK install are : 24.2 and 25.3

Gradle :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'
android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId 
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile group: 'com.google.code.gson', name: 'gson', version: '2.8.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.4.2'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:3.1.2'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
```

Comment: post the complete gradle to make it more understandable and also to solve your problem.

Comment: alright, I did it!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42374151/all-com-android-support-libraries-must-use-the-exact-same-version-specification)